# Set class on clicked connection

Tags: jsplumb

Is it possible to highlight at selected connection by setting a css class that works in most browsers.
I have tried to add a class that uses filter to create a "dropshadow" but that only works in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever a connection is clicked (selected) then you can modify its properties as I have changed the color of connection through setPaintStyle function. For more such functions refer the [API Document](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#Connection)

```
        jsPlumb.bind('click', function (connection, e) {

                 connection.setPaintStyle({fillStyle:'red'});

        });
```